# Laptop Screen Flashing

Tags: kernel, ati, brightness

i own a hp dv6-3080br laptop and its always been a pain in the ass to use with linux, the most stable system i could get running on it was ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13. i recently updated it to 14.10 with kernel 3.16 and yesterday 15.04 with kernel 3.19 and the bug i'll show you happens in both kernels, the screen seens to flash,making the brightness to high and low very fast, i ended up making a video to show how it goes (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IE_frY-Jk5g). this laptop has a radeon 5650 vga which seens to be completely abandoned by ati in driver matters, anyone can gimme a light in what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, i ended up finding that those flashes was caused by vgaswitcheroo switching from gpu to gpu(using dmesg), so i was able to set this feature off using grub and setting radeon.runpm=0 and the problem seens to be fixed!